# HERE API request OAuth 2.0 token with REST java

Tags: oauth, oauth-2.0, http-post, here-api, rest

I am trying to request a token to the Here API with Rest service java  in order to obtain OAuth 2.0 Token Credentials. I am blocked in the request level and constantly having the same error but according to the documentation I don't do anything wrong.

Here is the necessary code in REST Java to make the request.
The below code i tried.

```
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import javax.crypto.Mac;
import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.http.HttpEntity;
import org.apache.http.HttpHeaders;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.NameValuePair;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpPost;
import org.apache.http.client.utils.URLEncodedUtils;
import org.apache.http.entity.StringEntity;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.message.BasicNameValuePair;

public class here {

private static final String HMAC_SHA256 = "HmacSHA256";
private static final String ENC = "UTF-8";
private static Base64 base64 = new Base64();
private static String key = "MyKeyID"; // here.access.key.id from credential file
private static String secret = "MySecretKey" //here.access.key.secret
public static void main(String[] args) {


 HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
 long value = (System.currentTimeMillis() / 1000);
 int unique = (int) (Math.random() * 100000000);
 
 // These params should ordered in key
    List<NameValuePair> qparams = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("grant_type", "client_credentials"));
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_consumer_key", "MY_KEY_ID"));
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_nonce", ""
            + unique));
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_signature_method",
            "HMAC-SHA256"));
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_timestamp", ""
            + value));
    qparams.add(new BasicNameValuePair("oauth_version", "1.0"));
    System.err.println("query param->>>");
    
    // creating authentication signature
    String  signature = getSignature(URLEncoder.encode(
                    "https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token", ENC),
                    URLEncoder.encode(URLEncodedUtils.format(qparams, ENC), ENC));
  
    
   // comibining the params
    String authHeader = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=MY_KEY,"
           +"oauth_nonce="+unique+","
           +"oauth_signature="+signature+","
           +"oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256,"
           +"oauth_timestamp="+value+","
           +"oauth_version=1.0";
   
    
    HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token");
    httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    httpPost.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);
   
    String grant_type = "client_credentials";
    StringEntity input = new StringEntity("grant_type=" + grant_type);
    httpPost.setEntity(input);
    // output the response content.
    System.out.println("Token and Token Secrect:");
    
    HttpResponse    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
    HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
    
    if (entity != null) {
        
        InputStream instream = entity.getContent();
        int len;
        byte[] tmp = new byte[2048];
        try {
            while ((len = instream.read(tmp)) != -1) {
                System.out.println(new String(tmp, 0, len, ENC));
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}

private static String getSignature(String url, String params) throws UnsupportedEncodingException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, InvalidKeyException {
    
    StringBuilder base = new StringBuilder();
    base.append("POST&");
    base.append(url);
    base.append("&");
    base.append(params);
    System.out.println("Stirng for oauth_signature generation:" + base);
    // yea, don't ask me why, it is needed to append a "&" to the end of
    // secret key.
    byte[] keyBytes = (secret + "&").getBytes(ENC);

    SecretKey key = new SecretKeySpec(keyBytes, HMAC_SHA256);

    Mac mac = Mac.getInstance(HMAC_SHA256);
    mac.init(key);

    // encode it, base64 it, change it to string and return.
    return new String(base64.encode(mac.doFinal(base.toString().getBytes(
            ENC))), ENC).trim();

}}
```

And this is the error that I keep getting :

{"errorId":"ERROR-27b88f02-5d76-40ea-81d5-de6e70cf8464","httpStatus":401,"errorCode":401205,"message":"Unsupported signature method in the header. Require HMAC-SHA256","error":"invalid_request","error_description":"errorCode: '401205'. Unsupported signature method in the header. Require HMAC-SHA256"}

According to the documentation, https://developer.here.com/documentation/authentication/dev_guide/topics/using-aaa-javasdk-or-3rd-party-libraries.html

I develop the code based on the above api documentation but iam not getting the result.
Does anyone know how to fix this issue?

Comment: Hello i clear the above error : Unsupported signature method in the header. Require HMAC-SHA256 . But still i am not able to generate the token. Its showing one more error like errorCode: '401202'. Invalid Client Authorization header, expecting signed request format . I pasted the code below

Answer (score 0):

I tried this code

```
 HttpClient httpClient = HttpClientBuilder.create().build();
         String headers = "grant_type=client_credentials"+"&oauth_consumer_key=mykey"+"&oauth_nonce=uniquevalue"+"&oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256"+"&oauth_timestamp=timestamp"+"&oauth_version=1.0";
          String combine = "POST"+"\n&"+URLEncoder.encode("https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token", StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString())+"\n&"+URLEncoder.encode(headers, StandardCharsets.UTF_8.toString());
          Mac sha256_HMAC = Mac.getInstance("HmacSHA256");
          SecretKeySpec secret_key = new SecretKeySpec(("mysecretkey &").getBytes(), "HmacSHA256");
          sha256_HMAC.init(secret_key);
          String signature = Base64.encodeBase64String(sha256_HMAC.doFinal(combine.getBytes()));
           String authHeader = "OAuth "
                   + "oauth_consumer_key=\"X1E2a0ElfkaHx7aezqN5Hg-1234\","
                   +"oauth_nonce=\"uniquevalue\","
                   +"oauth_signature=\""+signature+"\","
                   +"oauth_signature_method=\"HMAC-SHA256\","
                   +"oauth_timestamp=\"timestamp\","
                   +"oauth_version=\"1.0\"";
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost("https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token");
            httpPost.addHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            httpPost.addHeader("Host", "account.api.here.com");
            httpPost.setHeader(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, authHeader);
            StringEntity input = new StringEntity("grant_type=" + "client_credentials");
            httpPost.setEntity(input);
            HttpResponse    response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
```

Its showing one more error like errorCode: '401202'. Invalid Client Authorization header, expecting signed request format. Please give some suggestion how to request a toke ?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to modify your code as-

// creating authentication signature

> String  signature = getSignature(URLEncoder.encode(
> "https://account.api.here.com/oauth2/token", ENC),
> URLEncoder.encode(URLEncodedUtils.format(qparams, ENC), ENC));

// comibining the params

> String authHeader = "OAuth oauth_consumer_key=MY_KEY,"
> +"oauth_nonce="+unique+","
> +"oauth_signature="+URLEncoder.encode(signature,"UTF-8")+","
> +"oauth_signature_method=HMAC-SHA256,"
> +"oauth_timestamp="+value+","
> +"oauth_version=1.0";

Answer (score 0):

I tried your solution and got the same error. There is some problem with the generated signature. I found this official Here Java SDK, which has classes to generate signature and Authorization Header.

https://github.com/heremaps/here-aaa-java-sdk/blob/acf6c7a982070f0b311c1741ce4887938b60df5b/here-oauth-client/src/main/java/com/here/account/auth/SignatureCalculator.java#L101

Hope this helps !